# Is there something wrong with my alpha-beta pruning algorithm?

Tags: java, minimax

I'm not sure what went wrong when I implemented the alpha-beta pruning. I've been going at this for 12 hours tweaking it, redoing it and I just can't find the problem (or I try to fix it and end up with more problems). Basically, 4 in a row or column to win and it's an 8 by 8 board.

My evaluation function is pretty much 
 `sum of (3 X's in a row - 3 O's in a row) * 3 + (2 X's in a row - 2 O's in a row) * 2`

**Edit:** I do not just have a problem with heap space, though it is one Each move is supposed to take 5 seconds at most, mines are running for 15 than crashing from `JAVA HEAP SPACE ERROR` after.

```
// Editing right now
}
```

```
// Iterative deepening and time-limited is ran
    }
```

```java
// Generates X successors sorted by utility
// Similar to the O one except just change the character

ArrayList<Node> generateXSuccessors() {
    char[][] copy = new char[8][8];
    char[][] temp = new char[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Go through all possible moves and add them to list
    // Must add arraylist and return from here, solve heap space error
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (temp[i][j] == '-') {
                temp[i][j] = 'X';
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
                        copy[k][l] = temp[k][l];
                    }
                }
                successors.add(new Node(copy));
                temp[i][j] = '-'; // Reset
            }
        }
    }

    //Sort list
    Collections.sort(successors);
    return successors;
}
```

With the current attempt which is shown above, I've been getting `Java Heap Space error`. Before that, the algorithm just ran with no stopping.

I'm not sure if I implemented it wrong or if my evaluation function is just really bad that it is causing such errors.

Edit:

```
// Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at FourInALine$Node.<init>(FourInALine.java:204)
    at FourInALine$Node.generateXSuccessors(FourInALine.java:238)
    at FourInALine.alphaBeta(FourInALine.java:134)
    at FourInALine.alphaBeta(FourInALine.java:157)
    at FourInALine.alphaBeta(FourInALine.java:137)
    at FourInALine.alphaBeta(FourInALine.java:157)
    at FourInALine.alphaBeta(FourInALine.java:137)
    at FourInALine.main(FourInALine.java:72)
```

Comment: @Dushyant Tankariya I've seen that post before but it doesn't help. I've edited my problem a bit to hit my problem better.

Comment: You're getting JAVA Heap Space error right! can you update your question with generated exception/log?

Comment: You are not showing where you create - and perhaps even more importantly, where you delete or clear - the `successors` list.   You declare it at the top, then assign it when calling `generateXSuccessors` - but that doesn't do a `new` or create it's own variable,but simply adds to (presumably) the class' instance variable (ie, the one that gets assigned to) - so I'm not sure why you're not getting an NPE when calling `add` on it.   Maybe it's somehow possible that list just keeps growing and growing.

Comment: @racraman Thank you! That solves my heap space error, I'm going to go try to solve the result and time error and if I can't will try to get some help later.